# Is it possible to access the Twilio destination number in a Twilio function called by Twilio Autopilot?

Tags: twilio

Using Twilio Autopilot, I see in the documentation that you can get the caller/originator from the `UserIdentifier` in a Twilio Function.  Is it possible to get the phone number the destination (one of my twilio numbers) messaged or dialed which kicked off the autopilot session?

My use case is to respond from the function with a greeting with different company names (bots would be identical except for company name.   ie.  "Thanks for contacting COMPANY NAME 1." or "Thanks for contacting COMPANY NAME 2." etc.  (In this case each company has their own distinct phone #).

My fallback is to create a bot for each company name that answers/greets, then redirects to the common workflow main task.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did some testing and the To is in the Memory object send to your Webhook.

Memory: {"twilio":{"voice":{"To":"+15555551212","From":"+15555551213","CallSid":"CAfffb9d435645b87363fa8afe5fxxxxxx","Direction":"inbound"}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Inbound Context](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/inbound-context) could be used to place this information in Autopilots Memory. The [Autopilot Request documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) doesn't seem to call out the To parameter. You could always capture the Autopilot Request and verify the parameters it is sending your application, to verify this is the case.

Comment: Thank you!  That helped a lot, and was able to create a redirect function to point to my different environments.

`exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
    let to = memory.twilio.voice.To;
    ...
    if("+18005551212" == to) {
        // my special actions here
    }`